# How to call an action without generating a view in grails

Tags: grails, view, controller, gsp

How can I call a method in one of my controller classes without grails trying to generate a view?

Comment: where are you calling from and what are you trying to do

Comment: An action in a controller always has to send something back to the user. But it doesn't have to be a GSP page, or HTML at all, you can construct a response of any type yourself. As nate suggests, we need to know what you want to achieve to be able to help you find a solution.

Comment: This question is perfectly valid. It's in the vein of what LinkedIn is doing with Scala and composing responses: http://engineering.linkedin.com/play/composable-and-streamable-play-apps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [redirect](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html) to another controller action.

```
class PuppyController {

   def woof() {
     redirect(action:'bark')
   }

   def bark(){
     response.write "Moo"
   }

}
```

At some point you should either write to the response or redirect to a method/closure that corresponds to a view so the user can receive the output.

If the method you're trying to call is on another controller, chances are YOAR DOING IT WRONG.

If, for example, I have a controller method that uploads a file, and another method that creates the filename for that file as a combination of some convention I make up (say timestamp + "pretty file for" + username) on another controller, you should promote that controller method to a [Service](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html) and inject it into both controllers.

Answer (score 3):

```
class FooController {

  def fooAction() {
    render("Successful call to fooAction")
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you can create a controller instance (via 'new' keyword) and then call the action of interest.
Please provide more details about what you want to do, so i might be able to give a better answer...